# Firebase Cloud Messaging test not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to get the Firebase Cloud Messaging to work. I am just trying a test for now. What I have done is everything in this post:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client?authuser=0#retrieve-the-current-registration-token

Then at that end you see this:

```
messaging.getToken().then((currentToken) => {
```

I then copy this `currentToken` and use it as a test by going to Firebase (the website) > Grow (sidebar) > Cloud Messaging (sidebar) > Send your first message (button) > Fill in a 'Notification title' and 'Notification text' > Send test message (blue button to right) > Add the `currentToken` I copied from above OR check a previously added one > Test (button) ... (see screenshot below)

[image]

I assume after clicking the 'Test' button it should send a notification to my phone (where I allow notifications and got the token from). I tested this with my pc and did not get a response either. Using Chrome on my pc and laptop for what that matters.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing an important part of adding the `gcm_sender_id` in the `manifest.json`. I followed this link exactly and it worked perfectly. You can use the Firebase Cloud Messaging testing platform instead of the Postman approach from the article:

https://codeburst.io/how-to-add-push-notifications-on-firebase-cloud-messaging-to-react-web-app-de7c6f04c920

Comment: Hey, if you don't mind can you tell me where did you find manifest.json? Should we create it by ourselves? I can't seem to find this manifest.json in my react native folders

Comment: Hi :) Yes you need to add it yourself. Check the link in my answer, it says so in the first few lines somewhere :)

Comment: Yes it says there need to be index.html, the problem is react native doesn't have index.html, so does it not matter if there is no index.html?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, sorry. I did this a very long time ago and can't remember at all hey. Maybe just create `manifest.json` and add it to every folder until it works? Not sure what else to tell you haha. Sorry!

Comment: Oh don't be, I really appreciate that you try to help me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to send a message from the Firebase cloud console but to an emulated Android device instead. No message would come through.

To make it work I had to uninstall and reinstall the app, simple as that.

*<sub>Answering this very old question because it's the first result that came up for my Google search and I wasted a lot of time "fixing" it. :)</sub>*